# Android Volley: How to flush and disable cache?

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

On my Android phone, I use Volley to do an HTTP POST request. The server sent an error response indicating a problem in the JSON data that I have passed. I have fixed the error but the server still display the same error. I have tried to pass an empty JSON file and I still get the same error response so the response clearly comes from some cached data.

I have tried to use those 2 things to clear and disable the cache but it doesn't help:

```
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

mRequestQueue.getCache().clear(); // <==== Here

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, dataObject, ...);

jsonObjReq.setShouldCache(false);  // <==== Here

mRequestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
```

How can I disable the Cache used by Volley or Android?

If I use Curl to execute the same request it works.

Thanks

Comment: please put your json foramt and specially your error here

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix the issue. I was using JsonObjectRequest and the server didn't understand the JSON file that I was sending.

I'm now using StringRequest() and it works.

Here is the non working code using JsonObjectRequest:
https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/forum/t/error-when-trying-to-add-an-end-device-from-http-api/55088/18?u=oliviergrenoble

And here is the working code using StringRequest:
https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/forum/t/error-when-trying-to-add-an-end-device-from-http-api/55088/21?u=oliviergrenoble

I have probably done something wrong in JsonObjectRequest version!